# How to find all the urls matching a certain pattern

Tags: google-search

I have a pattern let's say

> LetThe____Begin

I want all the urls like

> LetThePartyBegin.com
>
> LetTheCompetitionBegin.com
>
> LetTheCodingBegin.com

I am curious whether it is possible in google search. And please share any alternative to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allinurl: operator can search multiple words within URLs.

So you have to type -

> allinurl:Let The Begin

in your search and google will fetch all the pages which include this words in their url.

For more searching operators, refer to this [site](https://www.ontaheen.com/search-google-advance-google-search-tips/).